# Use dollar sign in PHP sprintf function with a %s string

Tags: php, wordpress, string, printf, money-format

This involves Wordpress syntax but I figured it was mainly a PHP problem.

I'm using this function:

```
$subject = sprintf( '%s New Customer Order %s for %s on %s', $blogname, $order->id, $order->get_total, $order->order_date );
```

to produce something like:
"SiteName New Customer Order #3715 for $40.00 on July 5th"

The problem is the $order_total outputs as a plain integer without dollar sign. Using $%s or \$%s doesn't work.. how can I append a dollar sign to the second %s variable?

Comment: Try concatinating it before `$order_id->get_total` like this: `sprintf( '%s New Customer Order %s for %s on %s', $blogname, $order->id, "$" . $order->get_total, $order->order_date );`

Comment: `'%$%s'` _should_ work, as the `%` is also the escape character in sprintf (from what I recall, anyway).

Comment: Using below snippet as solution already but thank you for above, tested and works for anyone else looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do :

```
$currency = '$';
$subject = sprintf( '%s New Customer Order %s for %s%01.2f on %s', 
      $blogname, 
      $order->id, 
      $currency,  
      $order->get_total, 
      $order->order_date );
```

Thus being able to change for different currencies, and format the amount to dollars and cents (or euros and cents, pounds and pennies etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually concatenate the dollar sign `$` before the `get_total` variable. Like this:

```
<?php

  //Test class
  class Order{
    public $id = "3333";
    public $get_total = "50.00";
    public $order_date = "07-06-2017";
  }
  $order = new Order();

  // Concatenate the dollar sign $ before the $order->get_total variable
  echo sprintf( '%s New Customer Order %s for %s on %s', "Test name", $order->id, "$" . $order->get_total, $order->order_date );

?>
```

Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/648e6873ebfe9ffc68eb54e61cc2e953be612dca

Comment: Using solution below but the concatenation also works! Thank you for alternative, already thought of a use for this outside the current circumstance.